# why ion-nav-back-button is not appearing in my project?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. I have created a simple tab based app on my own. I want back button to appear, when I switch from one tab to another tab. But actually it isn't appearing. I have used  directive also, but it also looks ineffective.

Following is the plunker link : https://embed.plnkr.co/B9ORrv/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic has different navigation history stack for each tabbed pages. When you switch between tabs, the nav stack is reset/emptied out. This means that [`$ionicHistory.backView()`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/) is `null` since there are no items in the stack. [`<ion-nav-back-button>`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/) shows only if `backView` exists. You have to implement your own history stack or make some tweaks if you really want back button. But even from UX perspective, you normally don't want back button on homepage of tabbed view.